# How to compute questionnaire total score and subscores by summing all and a selection of columns in R?

Tags: r, sum

I'm new in R and I'm having a little issue. I hope some of you can help me!

I have a data.frame including answers at a single questionnaire.

The rows indicate the participants.
The first columns indicates the participant ID.
The following columns include the answers to each item of the questionnaire (`item.1` up to `item.20`).

I need to create two new vectors:

1. **total.score** <- sum of all 20 values for each participant
2. **subscore** <- sum of some of the items

I would like to use a function, like a `sum(A:T)` in Excel.

Just to recap, I'm using R and not other software.

I already did it by summing each vector just with the symbol `+`

(data$item.1 + data$item.2 + data$item.3 etc...)

but it is a slow way to do it.

Answers range from 0 to 3 for each item, so I expect a total score ranging from 0 to 60.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`.

Comment: `rowSums(df[-1])` should give you the answer for `total.score`. For `subscore` which are those `some of the items` ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's use as example [this data from a national survey with a questionnaire](http://www.aelama.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/2016-SpanishSurveyBreastfeedingKnowledge-AELAMA.csv)

If you download the .csv file to your working directory

```
data <- read.csv("2016-SpanishSurveyBreastfeedingKnowledge-AELAMA.csv", sep = "\t")
```

Item names are `p01`, `p02`, `p03`...
Imagine you want a subtotal of the first five questions (from p01 to p05)

You can give a name to the group:

```
FirstFive <- c("p01", "p02", "p03", "p04", "p05")
```

I think this is worthy because of probably you will want to perform more tasks with this group (analysis, add or delete a question from the group...), and because it helps you to provide meaningful names (for instance "knowledge", "attitudes"...)

And then create the subtotal variable:

```
data$subtotal1 <- rowSums(data[ , FirstFive])
```

You can check that the new variable is the sum

```
head(data[ , c(FirstFive, "subtotal2")])
```

(notice that `FirstFive` is not quoted, because it is an object outside data, but `subtotal2` is quoted, because it is the name of a variable in data)

You can compute more subtotals and use them to compute a global score

---

You could may be save some keystrokes if you know that these variables are the columns 20 to 24:

```
names(data)[20:24]
```

And then sum them as

```
rowSums(data[ , c(20:24)])
```

I think this is what you asked for, **but I would avoid doing this way**, as it is easier to make mistakes, whick can be hard to be detected